# Backbone Collection Not Serializing with server

Tags: c#, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection, that has it's own save method:

```
var TranslatedTextCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: TranslationModel,
    url: window.applicationBaseUrl + 'TranslationEditor/TranslatedText',
    TotalPage: null,

    save: function (options) {
        Backbone.sync("create", this, options);
    },

    parse: function (response) {
        this.TotalPage = response.TotalPage;
        return response.list;
    }

});
```

I use this collection to return data from the server (a list of models, and also an additional TotalPage property. What I'm trying to do is to sync it back to the server after some changes on the models of the collection. When I hit save the server gets hit, but my collection is not populated with any data.

Here is my viewmodel (collection)

```
public class Translations
    {      
        public Translations()
        {

        }

        public Translations(IList<TranslationModel> translations)
        {
            list = translations;
        }

        public IList<TranslationModel> list { get; private set; }

        public int TotalPage { get; set; }
    }
```

The Backbone model properties are matching with the TranslationModel(C#) properties. The collection I'm saving has data when the save is called.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Right I'm passing a collection and expecting a single model on the server, that's not going to work I guess...